# CakePHP 2 can't find FireCake using Debug_kit

Tags: cakephp, firebug, firephp

I have been attempting to use CakePHP 2.0 and most of it works pretty well, however I have not been able to get console logging working with FireCake.  I have FireBug 1.8.3 and FirePHP 0.6.2 installed in Firefox 6.0.2 and my old Cake 1.3 project works fine.  For CakePHP 2.0 I downloaded the new version of DebugKit, put it in Plugins, added this to my AppController in Controllers folder:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'DebugKit.FireCake');

class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array('Cookie', 'DebugKit.Toolbar', 'RequestHandler', 'Session');
```

and this in my bootstrap

```
CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');
```

and in core

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

and then put this in one of my controller actions

```
FireCake::log($msg);
```

which generates an error like this

```
Fatal error: Class 'FireCake' not found in C:\Users\foo\Documents\Websites\cakephp-2.0.0.35\numbering\Controller\AppController.php on line 29
```

I can't figure out anything I might have missed from the instructions, so is there something duh-obvious I might be overlooking?  Or some extra import that is necessary?  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Matt

[edit]

I should add that the DebugKit menu appears as expected and functions, the problem is just FireCake.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation was incorrect for CakePHP v 2.0.  This is now required:

```
App::import('Lib', 'DebugKit.FireCake');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use

```
App::uses('FireCake', 'DebugKit.Lib');
```

if you are on CakePHP 2.2 or higher.

Comment: in which file I should put this line?